# How to get details of OS name, .net framework details for multiple servers using powershell?

Tags: powershell, operating-system, output, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get details of OS Name and .net framework details for multiple servers using PowerShell script  below.

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\servers.txt"

Foreach ($s in $servers)
{

write-host $s
$s.PSDrive
$s.PSChildName

Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "Specs:"
$OS = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).CSName
Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "`nOS:$OS"
$Bit = (Get-WMIObject win32_operatingsystem).name
Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "`nOS Bit: $Bit"
$name = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).OSArchitecture
Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "`nServer Name: $name"

$dotnet = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version
Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "`n.NET VERSION $dotnet"
$release = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full").Release
Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "`nRelease number: $release"
Add-Content C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.txt "`n----------------------------"

}
```

But i am getting details of the server in which i am running the script but not for other servers in the text file.

however write-host $s reads all the servers in the text file. Please help where i am doing wrong.

Comment: While you are looping over the list of servers, the commands you perform are always on the server you are running the code from. You never use variable `$` anywhere except in the Write-Host line. Then, why would you want the information in a text file and not in a structured file like CSV ? Finally, remove the versioned PowerShell tags and leave only the one(s) you actually use.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, you need to perform your code looping over the servers in your list and have that code run **on that server** instead of your own machine you are running the script from.

Also, I would have the code output **objects** instead of trying to add lines to a text file, so that you ca save the results in a structured format like CSV.

Try

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\servers.txt"

$specs = foreach ($s in $servers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $s -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Write-Host "Probing server $s"

        # you may need to add parameter -Credential and supply the credentials 
        # of someone with administrative permissions on the server
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {
            $os = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem)
            Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse |
            Get-ItemProperty -Name Version, Release -Erroraction SilentlyContinue | 
            Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | 
            ForEach-Object {
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    'ComputerName'     = $os.CSName
                    'Operating System' = $os.Caption
                    'Architecture'     = $os.OSArchitecture
                    'Net Version'      = [version]$_.Version
                    'Net Framework'    = $_.PsChildName
                    'Net Release'      = $_.Release
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Computer '$s' cannot be reached.."
    }
}

# remove extra properties PowerShell added
$specs = $specs | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId
# output on screen
$specs | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV file you can open in Excel
$specs | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\vinay\Desktop\specs.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```